# IOS AWSS3 SDK upload denied AWSS3BucketCannedACLPublicReadWrite

Tags: objective-c, amazon-s3, awss3transfermanager

Trying to upload image to Amazon S3 with **public** read permission.

## **UPLOAD DENIED:**

with ACL **'PublicReadWrite'**

```
_uploadRequest.ACL = AWSS3BucketCannedACLPublicReadWrite
```

## **UPLOAD SUCCESS:**

with ACL **'Private'**

```
_uploadRequest.ACL = AWSS3BucketCannedACLPrivate
```

any solution? direction?

---

---

## **MY CODE:**

**1. SET CERDITIALS**

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
initWithRegionType:_regionType
identityPoolId:_pool_id];
```

**2. CONFIGURATION**

```
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc]initWithRegion:_regionType credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];    
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

**3. CREATE UPLOAD REQUEST**

```
_uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
_uploadRequest.ACL = AWSS3BucketCannedACLPublicReadWrite;
```

**4. START Transfer MANAGER**

```
AWSS3TransferManager * transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
[[transferManager upload:_uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(AWSTask * task) {


    return nil;
}];
```

---

- ### bucket permissions are Read/Write ( for all users)

[image]

BUCKET POLICY:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy14...5",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt14.....5",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/UsersUploads"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Um - are you using the SDK or just making a POST ??

Comment: @Fattie, Using latest SDK

Comment: Is there a bucket policy set?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot 

i updated the answer, the policy in there
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy14.....",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt14.....5",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cheez.app/UsersUploads"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Note that your comment didn't paste properly, because the `*` characters were interpreted as markdown.  To prevent this in the future, you can surround short blocks of code or other literals with `\`` backticks in comments (or the body).  Adding to the question with an edit is even better, so thank you for that.

Comment: Presumably UsersUploads is a 'folder', so you need "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::UsersUploads/*"] so that PutObjectAcl is allowed against objects under UsersUploads/.

Comment: You shouldn't allow public access like this. Neither Any authenticated AWS user nor Everyone should have any permissions.  Your policy is incomplete, the resource should perhaps be `"arn:aws:s3:::cheez.app/UsersUploads/*"` and it also should not allow `"Principal": { "AWS": "*" }`.  Unfortunately, with such a mix of open permissions, it's difficult to pinpoint what isn't correct.

Comment: RESOLVED!
Thank you angels √√√ 
@jarmod
@Michael-sqlbot

i was need to add `*` at end of this policy line
`arn:aws:s3:::cheez.app/UsersUploads/*`

best regards to you all
took me long time to understand

Michael-sqlbot,
I'm giving open permissions because a reason that this will be an Application, that why i'm gives permissions to all users only for this bucket

Answer (score 0):

add * at the end of your "Resource" line
(in your bucket policy)

```
arn:aws:s3:::{bucketName}/{Folder}/*
```